# What is the error in the following code? (Python 2.7, matrices)

Tags: python-2.7, matrix

```
n= input("Enter size for matrix: ")
l=[[input("Enter number: ") for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)]
a=[[0 for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        a[j][i]=l[i][j]
for i in range(n):
    a[i]=a[i].reverse()
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print a[i][j],
    print
```

Basically, what I want to do is rotate a square matrix by 90 degrees. What I want is not a more efficient code snippet that can do the same, but the error in this code.

A NoneType error is raised. Please fix.

Comment: are you looking for a transpose or rotate? transpose of [[1, 2],[3, 4]] is [[1,3], [2, 4]], but rotate of [[1,2], [3,4]] is [[3,1],[4,2]]?

Comment: Rotate actually. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: ok, rather than transposing and using reverse function on it. You can do it in one for loop. But your technique is also good. If you are interested in doing in one for loop, please refer to my answer. As Jean Francois Fabre said, you do not need to re-assign when you are using reverse operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do that:

```
a[i]=a[i].reverse()
```

`a[i]` gets `None` as `reverse` works in-place and affects `a[i]` directly.

Just do:

```
a[i].reverse()
```

BTW this simplification leads us to a nice change to avoid indexes (and errors :)):

```
for l in a:
    l.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate a matrix by 90

l = [

[1, 2],

[3, 4]

]

rotated_l = [

[3, 1],

[4, 2]

]

**Code for rotating matrix:**

```
n= input("Enter size for matrix: ")
l=[[input("Enter number: ") for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)]
a =[[0 for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        a[i][j] = l[n-j-1][i]
print a
```

If you want to transpose a matrix

transposed_l = [

[1, 3],

[2, 4]

]

**Code for transposing a matrix:**

```
n= input("Enter size for matrix: ")
l=[[input("Enter number: ") for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)]
a =[[0 for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        a[i][j] = l[j][i]
print a
```